How do computer screens display an image with a different resolution than the display?
This is obviously a contrived toy example, but...
How would a 20x20 image be displayed on a 30x30 screen? Some pixels must be interpolated, yes? Is there a standard procedure for this or is it software-dependent?

It is software-dependent. These two related posts might help and be sure to check out the wiki page mentioned in the answer of the first post: What happens when you display a high resolution image on a low resolution screen?, Aspect Ratio Fitting for TV Screen

The image will get interpolated and resampled, how this is done is software-dependent. This is a nice read: https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/
